# Blur UI on High DPI windows system

Tags: wxwidgets

wxWidgets 3.1 claims to fix the Windows High DPI issues. It works too but I see blur UI (fonts/bitmaps) looks stretched.

I went through the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows

I did the manifest changes to make my application DPI-aware, it removed the blur effect but application layout went wrong, every layout looks smaller (unusable UI).

Note* issue more vigilant on 3K and 4K system. Hardcoded pixel sizes are not scaling (like 400px width button, 500pixel width panel etc).

Comment: do you use sizers or you explicitly setting the position/size of the controls?

Comment: Using sizer only, but fixing the size by calling SetMinSize() and SetMaxSize().

Comment: I have many child wxpanels in wxframe. These panels are layouted via sizers only, but making them fixed size ie. 300px or something by call SetSize(), SetMinSize() and SetMaxSize()

Comment: what if you remove those calls. will it behave correctly?

Comment: That will not be possible as there are many many hard-coded pixels in wxwidgets as well. And my application is 5 years old application, there are many places. I can't fix every where. Anyway application is working on all the platforms Mac or windows except I faced issue with high dpi windows machine

Comment: ok, can you reproduce it in the widgets sample? It has many panels... IIUC, all there is to do is to add SetSize() call. BTW, which Windows version you are testing it on?

Comment: I will go the office on Monday, I do not have high DPI system at home. Microsoft Windows Version 1703 (OS Build 15063.1206) WIndows 10 Pro

Answer (score 4):

wxWidgets gives you a (relatively simple) way to make your application work in high DPI, but doesn't -- and can't -- do it automatically for you, in particular only sizer-based layouts *without* hardcoded pixel sizes will work correctly and you do need to provide your own higher definition artwork.

Concerning the existing pixel values, the simplest (even though not really the best) way to make them work better is to put [FromDIP()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#aa934a31552633c076a87bca1100b0dc5) calls around them.

Also note that you don't need to do anything special for pixel values in XRC, they're already interpreted as being resolution-independent pixels and are scaled according to the DPI automatically.

Comment: If this is the case, can not we modify the SetSize(), SetMaxSize(), SetMinSize() in wxWindow class and use FromDIP() there it self.

Comment: This would break applications doing their own scaling (this is probably taste, but there are some) or using the result of text metrics functions to compute those sizes (and this is quite common).